# Full join two querys

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returned 385 strings

```
SELECT order_number
FROM `order` 
inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')
```

this returned 74 strings

```
SELECT order_number
FROM `order` 
inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')
```

How join it, that in that there are two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 try this:
 SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')

        ) as t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id
    UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')

        ) as t1
        RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('London')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id;
```

Comment: union returned one column with 459 strings, I need two columns with 385 and 74 strings

Comment: You have same timeframe for both query,I changed it. But now it show 385 value in first column and zero in second. Maybe it because `ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id;`? there is no same order_id in two columns

Comment: Yes, it is for that reason,That's why I proposed the union.

Comment: Edit my answer by emulating full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FULL JOIN, i.e. UNION ALL when using mysql:

*first_query* UNION ALL *second_query*

Comment: it is rerurned one column with data from two query. I need two columns with data for each of them

Comment: Use different aliases for every request: (first_query) AS 'first_7_days' UNION ALL (second_query) AS 'next_3_days'